# Is unblurring an image possible

Tags: functions, algorithms

I have been wondering if un-blurring an image is possible or not. Indeed, images produced by certain blurring algorithms are obviously irreversible if they remove information. I am more interested in this simple algorithm: For each pixel, set its value as the average of its neighbors and itself in the original image.

To analyze it in an easier way, I have come up with an equivalent question for one dimensional images:

1. An image is a sequence of numbers.
2. Its neighbors are simply the pixel on the left and right of itself.
3. Any pixels that are outside of the sequence have a value of zero.
4. Blur is a function $f$ where it takes a sequence of numbers, apply the rules described above, and return another sequence of numbers with the same length.

By my intuition I believed that the process is not reversible, therefore I tried to prove that $f$ is not a one to one function, such that more than one different images can lead to the same image.

Assume we have an image $S=\{a, b, c\}$, therefore
$$
f(S) = \Big \{\frac{0+a+b}{3}, \frac{a+b+c}{3}, \frac{b+c+0}{3}\Big \}
$$

To create a different image that will produce the same resulting image, we will have $S' = \{a + n, \_, \_\}$. The second pixel has to have a value of $b-n$, or else the average would not be the same, and so we have $S'=\{a + n, b - n, \_\}$. $c$ cannot change for the same reason, but the last pixel would not be correct because $\frac{(b-n)+c+0}{c} \ne \frac{b+c+0}{3}$.

It seems there does not exist any image that can produce the same image when blurred by this algorithm.

Questions:

1. Does this prove that the algorithm is reversible for all sequences with length 3 in one dimension?
2. Does this also prove the same for all length in one dimension and two dimension?

You can play with the algorithm [here in this fiddle I made](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2envs7ra/).

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDeconvolve.html

Comment: Is there a limit to the precision of the numbers you are using?

Comment: @QthePlatypus You can assume the values are real numbers with infinite precision.

Comment: @Moo That is very interesting! Is it using a similar algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution). In your case, $a,b,c$ can be solved by the system of equations
$$\begin{align*}
a + b &= 3f[S]_0 \\
a + b + c &= 3f[S]_1 \\
b + c &= 3f[S]_2
\end{align*}$$
In general, if you know the convolution kernel (usually a Gaussian matrix in the case of image bluring), and the kernel is non-zero, then the image can be deconvolved using Fourier transform.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know deconvolution is a thing, but what does Fourier transform have to do with this?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 The convolution theorem states $\mathcal F\{f * g\} = \mathcal F\{f\}\mathcal F\{g\}$, so if the convolved signal $f * g$ is known, $f$ can be obtained by $\mathcal F^{-1} \{\frac{\mathcal F\{f*g\}}{\mathcal F\{g\}}\}$.